# Neo4j service vs console

Tags: neo4j

What is the difference between running Neo4J as a service vs console in Windows?
There are 2 ways I can access the Neo4j browser http://localhost:7474/browser/ :

```
neo4j.bat install-service
```

when running for the first time, then

```
neo4j.bat start
```

another is

```
neo4j.bat console
```

After doing any of one these the Neo4j browser loads. I don't understand why there are 2 commands that seemingly do the same thing. The tangible difference I can see is that `neo4j.bat start` takes me back to the prompt, while `neo4j.bat console` does not. What are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Console mode requires the terminal window to stay open**

When you execute using the `console` subcommand, all output is printed to the current console window. If the console is exited, either via Ctrl+<kbd>C</kbd>, closing the terminal, or sending some termination signal to it, the neo4j process is also killed.

When you execute it with the `start` subcommand, the neo4j process is detached from the console, and will continue running even if the console window is closed. It will remain running until either it fails or is shut down by invoking the `stop` subcommand (or any other subcommand that makes it stop).

Technically it could also be killed by anything that kills processes as well; i.e. TaskManager, signals, etc.

Comment: I see. I initially thought "console" provides a separate browser-based management console and service is for running the normal Neo4J browser. thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

A [Windows service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service) is a program that runs in the background.

The [neo4j Windows service](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.3/installation/windows/#_windows_service) is such a background service, and it can be controlled via the neo4j.bat `start`, `stop`, `restart`, `status`, and `uninstall-service` commands. These commands run in the foreground and deliver the command to the background service, returning you to the prompt when the command is done.

The [neo4j Console application](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.3/installation/windows/#windows-console) just executes the neo4j server in the foreground, and so you will not be returned to the prompt until you terminate the application (usually via `Ctrl-C`).